# Equivalent of Flash's BitmapData.hitTest() in HTML5 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, html, canvas

I would like to know if there is existing equivalent methods in JavaScript (for HTML5 supported browsers) that can evaluate a bitmap-on-bitmap hitTest like Flash does.

Also, how could a "blur-filter" be achieved?
Can existing DIV / SPAN tags be "drawn" (like Flash's BitmapData.draw() method) into a bitmap object, so it can be used for "hitTest" purpose on the canvas?

I think I may have the HTML5 jargon all wrong here, but hopefully this makes somewhat some sense.

Are there any built-in methods to check if bitmaps touch eachother, at pixel-level evaluation?

Thanks!

Comment: I would be opened to a server-side answer too, such as running a SWF on the server that would do the BitmapData.hitTest... but is there such a thing? Like some sort of light-weight Flash Player runtime for servers?

Comment: Given that the HTML Canvas uses floating-point transforms, what would you expect to happen when you had a rotated, scaled-down bitmap tested against a differently-rotated bitmap that is offset by 0.25 pixels and non-uniformly scaled to be very wide?

Comment: I'm not sure how your comment (question) fits in this context. Rhetorical question? Sorry it's just a bit over my head the way you phrased it.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, there are no methods in HTML Canvas or Context to determine if two regions overlap. No tests for non-square regions of non-transparent pixels overlapping, no tests for transformed bounding boxes overlapping, no tests even for overlapping axis-aligned bounding boxes. Any such hit testing will need to be done by you or a higher-level API tracking individual bitmaps. The Canvas/Context is a *non-retained* low-level pixel blitting and drawing API.
2. No, you cannot serialize the rendering of HTML elements into a canvas image (other than using `drawImage()` to copy images and/or canvases). This includes attempting to capture content that is drawn underneath a transparent/semi-transparent canvas. There are security problems if this is allowed, and so it is not.

   - However, you can 'blur' content *already drawn* to the canvas by using `getImageData()` to get the raw pixels, then manipulating the pixel values, and then using `putImageData()` to push the modified pixels back to the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

PlayMyCode has a great step-by-step explanation of a [Javascript per-pixel collision detection function](http://www.playmycode.com/blog/2011/08/javascript-per-pixel-html5-canvas-image-collision-detection/) that works very much like Actionscript's hitTest.